# To find the total no. of six digit numbers that can be formed having property that every succeeding digit is greater than preceding digit.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a question and got strucked on this..
To find the total no. of six digit numbers that can be formed having property that every succeeding digit is greater than preceding digit.
Please guide me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm I the only one who is unsure what 'succeeding digit' refers to? For the number '123', I consider the '3' to be the first digit, so I would say that 2 is the succeeding digit of 3. At least one answer below uses the opposite formulation and says that 2 is the preceding digit of 3. It may be clearer if you say 'every digit to the right is greater than the one to the left' or whatever you intended.

Comment: @WilliamForcier: I think yours is the unusual definition, but regardless, it shouldn't change the answer, except that one might not want to include, say, 012345 whereas 543210 would be perfectly fine.  We'd have to get a ruling from the judge on that.

Answer (score 21):

Hint: Once you've picked six different digits, there is only one way to arrange them to satisfy the conditions given.

Comment: nice and simple  +1 :)

Comment: @sasha: Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

Or to look at it another way. There is only one 9 digit number with this condition 123456789.

What about 8 digits?: there are nine answers
12345678,
12345679,
12345689,
12345789,
12346789,
12356789,
12456789,
13456789,
23456789.

So all I have done is strike out each digit in turn. $9\times 1$ digit = 9 possibilities.
For 7 digits, you need to strike out 2 digits - how many ways of doing this are there?
does  $\binom{9}{2}$ ring a bell?
And so for 6 digit number you need to lose 3 digits.........