# Number of six-digit integers with increasing digits

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many six-digit positive integers can you write, if each number must have strictly increasing digits from left to right?

How is it allowed to use:

$$ \binom{9}{3}$$

Because this says out of $9$ numbers choose $c$ **the order does NOT matter.**

But CLEARLY as the question indicates, the order **does matter!** We have to pick increasing numbers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you pick six different digits, there is only one way to arrange them so that the digits are increasing.  I would view the answer as $9\choose 6$, but of course this is equal to $9\choose 3$.

Comment: How only one way? $6, 5, 4...$ or $5, 3, 6..$?

Comment: @Lebes: But you're required to select the strictly increasing order of your digits.  So if for instance you pick the digits $\{3,7,8,2,6,1,4\}$, the only permissible $6$ digit number is $1234678$.

Comment: yes, but $\binom{9}{6}$ means, from 9 choose $6$ and order doesnt matter?

Comment: @Lebos: Think of this as a two-stage process: Stage 1: Choose six distinct digits from $9$ (can be done in $9\choose 6$ ways).  Stage 2: Then arrange these digits in increasing order ($1$ way).

Comment: If there were $2$ ways, you would do: $2 \binom{9}{6}$? Just supposing? (+1)

Comment: Yes, for instance if you were interested in either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing digits (although in the strictly decreasing case we'd stipulate all digits nonzero).

Comment: This is hilarious. You've [already answered this question before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121652/to-find-the-total-no-of-six-digit-numbers-that-can-be-formed-having-property-th/1121655#1121655) and you are once again the top-voted and accepted answerer for the same question.

Comment: @paw88789: "the only permissible 6 digit number is 1234678" - I count 7 digits... :)

Answer (score 11):

Another way to look at this is: take any six-digit number in which the digits are increasing from left to right. Insert the three digits that were not used, keeping the digits in increasing sequence. For each possible starting number there is only one way to do this; for example,
$$ 235678 \mapsto \mathbf 1\ 23\ \mathbf 4\ 5678\ \mathbf 9 \mapsto 1 23 4 5678 9.$$

The process is reversible. That is, you can get any of the desired six-digit numbers
with digits increasing from left to right by starting with $123456789$ and knocking out
three digits.

In fact, there is one and only one way to get each possible six-digit number with the 
desired property by removing three digits from $123456789$.
Hence the number of six-digit numbers you can get is simply the number of ways you
can choose three digits to remove from among the nine digits of  $123456789$,
or $\binom93$.

Of course the order in which you remove the three digits does *not* matter;
all that matters is in the end, which three digits you have removed.

---

In understanding these kinds of counting problems in general, rather than saying
"the order matters" or "the order does not matter",
it may be better to ask, "Can I produce *different outcomes* by choosing the
items in a different order?"

For example, if I want to count how many three-digit numbers there are with
no zeros and no two digits the same,
I can choose three digits one at a time and write them down in the order in
which I chose them; each sequence of choices gives a new number to be counted.
For example, $231$ and $123$ are both counted as distinct outcomes.
This gives me $9\cdot8\cdot7 = \frac{9!}{6!} = 504$ possible outcomes.

But if I am only allowed to write three-digit numbers whose digits are in increasing
order, I cannot count $231$ and $123$ as distinct outcomes.
One way to deal with this is to say, if I choose $2$ first, I cannot choose $1$
later, so the sequences of choices $231$ is impossible.
An easier way to deal with this, however, is to allow myself to choose the digits
subject only to the restriction that I cannot choose a digit that was previously chosen;
but after choosing the numbers, I have to put them into increasing order.
So it is possible to choose in sequence either $2,3,1$ or $1,2,3$, but each of these
results in the same outcome ($123$) in the end.
In this way I see there are $3! = 6$ different sequences of numbers that can be chosen
(one for each of the $3!$ permutations of three digits)
that all result in the same outcome (namely, those three digits arranged
in increasing order).
So if I take all the possible sequences of choices, and divide by $3!$,
I get the correct answer, $\binom 93 = 84.$

In the first case I was able to produce different outcomes depending on the order
in which I chose the digits. Hence I use the formula for counting permutations.
In the second case, I was not able to produce different
outcomes in that way (because of the restriction that the digits in the result
must be written in a certain sequence), so I use the formula for counting combinations.

Comment: This uses the strategy used by the answerer Neal [in the original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121652/to-find-the-total-no-of-six-digit-numbers-that-can-be-formed-having-property-th/1121655#1121655).

Comment: @user314 I posted before a link was made to the other question; I might have posted differently otherwise. But there are some subtle differences in the answers, just as there is a subtle difference in the questions. (This question doubted the correctness of "unordered" combinations to solve an "ordered" problem.)

Comment: I agree.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Generalization:
$$
\binom{n+m}{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+j}{n}
$$
Where set of size $n+m$ consists of elements $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots a_{n+m} \}$. Split the list $\binom{n+m}{n}$ into subsets where $a_n$ (in your case $a_1 = 4$) is the smallest number, $a_{n-1}$, etc.